# xcopy failed on TFS build server

Tags: tfsbuild, xcopy

I have following command which is executed after build in post build events:

```
xcopy /Y  $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)Binaries
```

This works fine on my PC. But When I checkin it to the TFS with gated build it ends with not specified error. The command which is executed on the build server is:

```
 xcopy /Y  "C:\Builds\1\MyProject\MyProject Gated Check-in\Binaries\Common.dll" "C:\Builds\1\MyProject\MyProject Gated Check-in\Sources\MyProject\Binaries"
```

When I run this command on the build server from the commandline it works fine.

Can you advise to me what could be wrong on this?

thanks

Comment: No missing double quotes here? You have blanks in your path.

Comment: yes, it was the problem. thanks!